Angular Tanstack Query ExplicitType for injectQuery()
I am trying to use Tan stack Query in Angular And my VS Code has been complaining that I have to explicitly mention type for result of the inject Query as  CreateQueryResult<Data, Error>; where as non of the example in their documentation uses any explicit types.
for example in the docs:
class ServiceOrComponent {
  filter = signal('')

  todosQuery = injectQuery(() => ({
    queryKey: ['todos', this.filter()],
    queryFn: () => fetchTodos(this.filter()),
    // Signals can be combined with expressions
    enabled: !!this.filter(),
  }))
}


where as What I have is whihc doesnt seem right for some reason. My question is that Do I have to have the type for every injectQuery? as CreateQueryResult
class ServiceOrComponent {
  filter = signal('')

  todosQuery: CreateQueryResult<Data, Error>; = injectQuery(() => ({
    queryKey: ['todos', this.filter()],
    queryFn: () => fetchTodos(this.filter()),
    // Signals can be combined with expressions
    enabled: !!this.filter(),
  }))
}


Very simple you just forgot to convert this to promise, you need tot wrap the func call with lastValueFrom to make it a promise since its promise not Observable
class ServiceOrComponent {
  filter = signal('')

  todosQuery = injectQuery(() => ({
    queryKey: ['todos', this.filter()],
    queryFn: () => lastValueFrom(fetchTodos(this.filter())),
    // Signals can be combined with expressions
    enabled: !!this.filter(),
  }))
}

